# Spring table relationship problems

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have two entities Product and Image, the image has a Product foreign key.

When i try to run the code i get the following error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'imageRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'imageRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property product found for type Image!    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]     at
>   model.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'imageRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property product found for type Image!    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     ... 19 common
>   frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property product found for type Image!    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:77)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:76)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:247)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:378)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:89)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:64)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     ... 29 common
>   frames omitted

Product entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Integer parent_product_id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getParent_product_id() {
        return parent_product_id;
    }

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    public void setParent_product_id(Integer parent_product_id) {
        this.parent_product_id = parent_product_id;
    }


}
```

Image Entity

```
@Entity
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String type;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product_id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Product getParent_product_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(Product product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }


}
```

My ImageRepository

```
package model;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface ImageRepository extends CrudRepository<Image, Long> {

    List<Image> findByProduct_id(String id);
}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repository should be:

```
public interface ImageRepository extends CrudRepository<Image, Long> {

    List<Image> findByProductId(Integer id);
}
```

Your `Product` Entity should  be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Transient
    private Integer parentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Product parentProduct;

    //getters/setters

}
```

And your `Image` Entity should be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    //getters/setters


}
```

Comment: When i`m calling the endpoint to create a new product, how do i pass the product on the parent one?

Comment: By calling the `setParentProduct` method

Comment: Ok, but it receives now a Product object, how do i test it on Postman for example, as i can't pass a product object

Comment: That is a totally different question than the original one. If you have a `@Controller` class you can pass only the parent product id, then load the parent product via the `ProductRepository` I suppose you already have and set it to your new product. You understand that your question has very few info to be able to answer you promptly. Also you can test it not only with postman but with a unit test, again that is another question than the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the name of the **product_id** to **product** and change the String type from the repository to Product !
Also try this query :

```
@Query("select * from Image image where image.product=:product")
List<Image> findByProduct(@Param("product") Product product);
```